# Why is “a” used before “smoke” in this sentence?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

> I only have half an hour-barely time for **a** smoke  and a cup of
>   tea.

*Smoke* is uncountable so why is there an article used?

Comment: "Smoke" is a synonym for cigarette. https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cigarette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, “a smoke” is a cigarette. “Have a smoke” means go out and have a cigarette.

> > 6a(1) : something (such as a cigarette) to smoke

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smoke

You are correct that some other meanings, such as the stuff that rises from a fire, are uncountable nouns.